# Custom metadatatype beta picklist fields in production

Tags: custom-metadata

I'm trying to deploy some new custom metadatatypes from a sandbox to production, but the types contain picklist fields, which appear to be unavailable on my production org even though they are the same release. I've read that picklists on metadatatypes are a beta feature, could this be the problem? How can I enable this field type in my production org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to contact Salesforce support and ask them to enable the "Restrictive Picklists" permission on your production org.